# Plugin Javascript(maybe ajax) is not working in my wordpress custom theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am new in wordpress theme development. I am developing a theme and I used `WP-Live Chat by 3CX`
and `Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms` plugins in my wordpress theme. I can't figure out the actual issues. Please help- *my issues are*

For: **WP-Live Chat by 3CX**

[image]

The start chat button not working. This problem happens because of the plugin js. I contacted their support they also said plugin js not working properly. I showed them my functions `wp_enqueue_scripts` how I implemented. But they said they can't help more about this.

For: **Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms**

The first step data is not showing in the second step form. I contacted their support also but they also said this is js problem.
[image]
[image]

[My website link](https://designworldusa.com/)
I can't figure out the issues. I included my theme `js` and `css` in `functions.php` like

```
function themename_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('othemename-jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.min.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome.min1849.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, '1.1', 'all');
    wp_register_style('othemename-owlcarousel', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('othemename-owlcarousel');
    wp_register_style('othemename-owlcarousel-theme', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('othemename-owlcarousel-theme');
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    wp_enqueue_script('othemename-owlcarouseljs', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('themename-jquerymigrate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min330a.js', array(), '20151215', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('themename-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '20151215', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('themename-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/themeac31.js', array(), '20151215', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('themename-extra', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/extra.js', array(), '20151215', true);

    if (is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
        wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_scripts');
```

Is this because of I am not properly developing my theme? If not then what could be the problem. Please help.

Comment: The console is displaying an error that `onepress_js_settings` is not defined. I'm not sure if it's related or not with your issue. What the documentation of this chat says about integrating it?

Comment: I don't know in `consol onepress_js_settings` is not defined. Either it will be a variable or a function. I do not have enough knowledge in javascript. But I am trying to find out.

Comment: Well, actually you need it. In this case, I recommend you to hire someone else to solve this problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try to solve this first because I wanna learn js. Then if I failed, I will hire someone.

Comment: If you want to learn JS, that's good. Sorry if I misunderstand you. You should figure out where in your theme `onepress_js_settings` should be set. Maybe you should try to deactivate all plugins to see if this error disappear. It's very common to have JS conflicts in themes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I resolved the same (or similar) issue with the OnePress WP Theme just now by updating the jQuery version in use.

It appears the original question asker has updated the chat script on their website to Tawk.to since posting the question, and Tawk.to's chat is functioning fine as far as I can tell.

Do you need further help with the issue? If so, please continue reading for more information on how I found this post and what I used to resolve.

I found the same "onepress_js_settings is not defined" error message mentioned in the comments under the question in the Developer Tools Console tab of Chrome.

We also have Tawk.to active on the site I just fixed it on as it happens.

After an overnight WP auto-update, his site ran into some Jquery conflicts producing the "OnePress" theme error message.

Why did I try a jQuery Update?

I found a thread on WordPress.com where someone else had the same error message. Their thought was that Bootstrap 4.0 required a newer version of jQuery than was in use.

Here is the article I found for reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-compatible-with-bootstrap-4-not-load-jquery-3/

Additionally, here is a link to the free plugin that fixed the problem by updating the jQuery version for me by simply installing and activating it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-updater/

Anyone else who finds this post and maybe the asker as well since you mentioned wanting to learn more about JavaScript, and in this instance, I believe jQuery specifically.